# Python with Azure KeyVault

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

I'm trying to follow the examples here https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python to learn about Azure. In the example they suggest you get the secret_version by using the API `KeyVaultClient.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_id)`

KeyVaultClient.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_id) is suppost to return SecretItemPaged which is an interator. However i can't seem to iterate it.

Here is my attempt at a part of the example

```
client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)
secret_versions = client.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_id) 
for item in secret_versions:
    print(item)
```

This gives me the error

> azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.key_vault_error_py3.KeyVaultErrorException:
>   Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'

I also tried converting it to a list but that gives me the same error.

```
client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)
secret_versions = list(client.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_id))
```

Comment: Kindly check the credentials.

Comment: They should be fine. If i just run 

client = KeyVaultClient(credentials)
secret_versions = client.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_id)

it works so i assume they're fine

Comment: Can you kindly check the type of output returned by the function by printing it in your output console

Answer (score 0):

Well turns out the documentation confused me. They refer to secret_name as secret_id. Since they use another variable later called SECRET_ID i assumed secret_id = SECRET_ID

But that is not the case. SECRET_ID = the secret id of your secret while the secret_id is actually secret_name. That is the name of your secret.

```
secret_versions = list(client.get_secret_versions(vault_url, secret_name)) 
for item in secret_versions:
    print(item)
```

This works. Thanks for trying to help Deepak Ahire, hope i didn't waste your time

Comment: My pleasure, always!